# Applying Filtering to a list which Removes Items

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to filter a list of input data.

This list includes some domains (Example: aws.amazon.com, amazon.com, www.amazon.com, .amazon.com, www.example.com, example.com).

I had to check if there are duplicate entries and remove them from the list.

After filtering the list should only contain **amazon.com and example.com** (from the example above).

```
>>> destinations = ['test.aws.amazon.com', 'aws.amazon.com', 'amazon.com', '.example.com', 'url.example.com', 'net.example.com']
>>> cleaned_list = destinations.pop()
>>> for destination in destinations:
...     results = re.findall('.*%s' % destination, ' '.join(destinations))
...     shortest = None
...     for erg in results:
...         if not shortest:
...             shortest = erg
...         else:
...             if len(shortest.split('.')) > len(erg.split('.')):
...                 print('shortest == %s' % shortest)
...                 shortest = erg
...                 cleaned_list.remove(erg)
... 
>>> 
>>> cleaned_list
'net.example.com'
```

But after running that code just one domain is left in "cleaned_list"

Thanks for your help.
BR

Comment: Can you explain what `results = re.findall('.*%s' % destination, ' '.join(destinations))` is trying to accomplish?

Comment: What if `'alpha.test.apple.com'` and `'test.apple.com'` were added to `destinations`; what should the result be then, and why?

Comment: @ScottHunter the list could also contain `dev.anydomain.com.pl and anydomain.com.pl` in that case `anydomain.com.pl` should be left

Answer (score 3):

### How to do it quicker:

You can just use a set, to achieve the same thing:

```
destinations = ['test.aws.amazon.com', 'aws.amazon.com', 'amazon.com', '.example.com', 'url.example.com', 'net.example.com']

primary_domains = set([])

for destination in destinations:
    primary_domain = '.'.join(destination.split(".")[-2:])
    primary_domains.add(primary_domain)

print(primary_domains)
```

Result:

```
{'amazon.com', 'example.com'}
```

### How it works:

`set` cannot have duplicate values. If you add the same thing multiple times, you'll still only have one of them

`destination.split(".")` splits on the dots. `[-2:]` grabs the last two items. `'.'.join()` joins it back with dots

### Why yours doesn't work:

1. Cleaned list is just `net.example.com` because when you `cleaned_list = destinations.pop()` it takes the last item from `destinations`, removes it, and assigns it to `cleaned_list`
2. Because the regex fill match everything that comes before it, and because regex is greedy, you'll get as `results`:

```
['test.aws.amazon.com']
['test.aws.amazon.com aws.amazon.com']
['test.aws.amazon.com aws.amazon.com amazon.com']
['test.aws.amazon.com aws.amazon.com amazon.com .example.com url.example.com net.example.com']
['test.aws.amazon.com aws.amazon.com amazon.com .example.com url.example.com']
['test.aws.amazon.com aws.amazon.com amazon.com .example.com url.example.com net.example.com']
```

3. Even if those 2 worked, you might remove items from your cleared list, that you've already removed, resulting in an error.

### How to do it, if you want to filter not just by primary domain

As you've said in a comment, if you sometimes have to deal with not just primary domains, here is a more generic solution, for finding strings, that are part substrings of other strings:

```
import itertools

destinations = ['test.aws.amazon.com', 'aws.amazon.com', 'amazon.com', '.example.com', 'url.example.com', 'net.example.com', 'dev.whatever.company.com.pl', 'company.com.pl']

substrings = {}

for v1, v2 in itertools.product(destinations, destinations):
    if v1 in v2 and v1 != v2:
        substrings[v1] = substrings.get(v1, []) + [v2]

substrings = {key: value for key, value in substrings.items() if not any(k in key and key != k for k in substrings.keys())}

print(substrings)
```

Result:

```
{'amazon.com': ['test.aws.amazon.com', 'aws.amazon.com'], '.example.com': ['url.example.com', 'net.example.com'], 'company.com.pl': ['dev.whatever.company.com.pl']}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. This is an good solution but does not fix my problems.. This is an dynamic list provides by customer.. That list could also contain url like ** dev.whatever.company.com.pl and company.com.pl** so i'm not able to split and take always the last two parts of that.. That was the reason why i am trying to compare the entries from the list, find the shortest one for a domain and remove the others

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. I'll update my answer soon. Please update your question, with appropriate examples, so this specification is clear

Comment: Many thanks for your help! One additional question.. After running my tests i found out, that in some cases of defined domains `fix.other.com, other.com, .other.com` i had to use `.other.com` because the that is the correcter form (includes all subdomains) instead of `other.com`.  I use this for deploying and proxy configuration and so i had to find the best option for the proxy urls..

Comment: Well, you'll need to be more specific about what "some cases" means. You can do a specific check for those cases, if it starts with a `.`, and add it if it's missing.

Comment: Here is one example.. `['test.aws.amazon.com', 'aws.amazon.com', '.amazon.com', '.example.com', 'url.example.com', 'net.example.com', 'www.north.com', 'north.com', '.mydest.co.at', 'mydest.co.at', '213.12.23.22/32', 'amazon.com', 'www.somother.net', 'mystuff.com.pl']`
I had to cleanup this list... If there is an url `'example.com, .example.com' only `.example.com`should be left (. in front means, wildcard for all subdomains) and others which are unique should be left..

Comment: Already updated my answer to support the behaviour you've asked

Answer (score 0):

## Solution for cleaning up the list of destinations

Generate a rule for squid proxy.

Customer is sending a list of domains and IPs. This list has to be checked and filtered.

- Filter out all duplicate entries
- If domain has a `dot` in front, this means that all subdomains will be included `(.examle.com includes for example whatever.example.com)` so every other subdomain from that url has to be removed from destinations list.
- If a domain has NO `dot` in front the proxy clearing is dedicated for that url, so in case there is `mystuff.com and subdomain.mystuff.com` in the list, both should be remain in the same.

**Python code for that solution**

```
>>> destinations = ['test.aws.amazon.com', 'aws.amazon.com', '.amazon.com', 'example.com', 'url.example.com', 'times.org', 'net.example.com', 'www.north.com', 'north.com', '.mydest.co.at', 'mydest.co.at', '213.12.23.22/32', 'amazon.com', 'www.somother.net', '.amazon.at']
>>> destinations = set(destinations)
>>> for d1, d2 in itertools.product(destinations, destinations):
...     if d1 != d2 and d1[0] == '.':
...         if re.findall(d1[1:], d2):
...             destinations.remove(d2)
... 
>>> destinations
['.amazon.com', 'example.com', 'url.example.com', 'times.org', 'net.example.com', 'www.north.com', 'north.com', '.mydest.co.at', '213.12.23.22/32', 'www.somother.net']
```

**Thanks to "tituszban" for the help**